# Using NSAlert beginSheetModalForWindow with contextInfo

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I get the following error from the alert sheet code below when the user hits the default button:

> -[NSRectSet objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x400876300

Btw, the code works fine in Snow Leopard but the problem comes up in Lion.

```
NSMutableDictionary * extrasDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[extrasDict setObject:@"http://www.google.com" forKey:@"link"];

NSAlert * alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Published Successfully"
                                  defaultButton:@"View Collage on Facebook"
                                alternateButton:nil
                                    otherButton:@"Cancel"
                      informativeTextWithFormat:@"Successfully published to Facebook."];

[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:myWindow
                  modalDelegate:self
                 didEndSelector:@selector(publishedSuccessfullyDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                    contextInfo:extrasDict];             


- (void)publishedSuccessfullyDidEnd:(NSAlert *)alert
                         returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode
                        contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    if (returnCode == NSAlertDefaultReturn) {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:[(NSDictionary*)contextInfo objectForKey:@"link"]]]; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I can't see what the source of the error is. It must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Btw, the code works fine on Snow Leopard but the problem comes up in Lion.

Comment: If you have Xcode 4.1, check the docs on all the methods you are using. One of them might have changed. Sorry, no better plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using garbage collection, store `extrasDict` in an instance variable – anywhere, doesn't matter – so it isn't released at the end of the run loop. You need the dictionary to stick around until the `didEndSelector` can act on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't believe you have to do this (you are correct though, your answer saved me). Why doesn't #beginSheetModalForWindow hold onto the contextInfo until the method is done running?

Comment: I think it's because `contextInfo` could be absolutely anything – it's not limited to being an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your coding part. It's working well. Check the remaining part of the coding.